# jQuery datepicker issue, it pops twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I need to enable a textbox based on the date change in jQuery Datepicker. So I have written a code like this:

HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="support_due_date" class="form-label">Due date if any</label>
    <div class="input-group date" data-target-input="support_due_date">
      <input type="text" id="support_due_date" name="support_due_date" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#support_due_date" value="<?php echo set_value('support_due_date');?>" />
      <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#support_due_date" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo form_error('support_due_date'); ?>
  </div>
</div>

$("#support_due_date").datepicker({    
     onClose: function(){      
      $("#justify_urgency").removeAttr("readonly");    
      var todays_date = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
     }
  });
```

Once I click on datepicker, it gives calendar popped up and if I click on a date then it gives another datepicker without any CSS, just green color dates.

Why this calendar pops up twice?

I am using  AdminLTE theme so daterangepicker and calendar are the js provided from AdminLTE theme only.

Image of error

[image]

[Initial Page looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIw0v.png)

[Once we click on calendar, it gives this weird calendar again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcN2x.png)

[When I select date again, it enables textbox to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz4UG.png)

Comment: Guess is that `id=support_due_date` is a `type='date'`  so you're seeing the browser date picker and you've not included (correctly) the datepicker.css so you're not seeing the css for the datepicker.  Without more code, impossible to tell.  See [mcve].

Comment: *just green color dates* - they look blue to me... they look like unstyled `<a>` which would indicate the datepicker.css is missing

Comment: but why it is popping two times? Second-time CSS is not being loaded as you said but why second-time popup?

Comment: What's it look like the first time?

Comment: Can you [edit] and provide a complete snippet? (you can also use jsfiddle.net, but a snippet is preferred) Including exactly which datepicker.js you're using (from a CDN, not local to your project) so we can see the issue?  Or at least, enough code (the HTML of the input) so we can try to recreate it.

Comment: @freedomn-m I have modified the code, please see to this and let me know if any further data is required.

Comment: @freedomn-m any suggestion?

Comment: One possible reason:  if the datepicker is set to display on input focus, it will display when that input gets focus.  So you click in the input, which show datepicker, you select a date, you then run some other code that ends up with your input having focus and the datepicker reappearing.

Comment: I also note that your 2nd datepicker doesn't look like the first (not just missing css).  Eg no feb 27/28 and it stops on 31st, while 2nd (screenshot) shows 6 weeks   This implies to me that **it's a different datepicker js** showing.  Check you don't have multiple datepickers defined and that your input is type `text` so that the browser datepicker is not shown (but you state this has been done)

Comment: Your next step is to *reproduce* the issue.  Ideally here in a stack snippet ([see here for details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/2181514)), but maybe in a jsfiddle if that's easier.  Start from scratch (no code/js/html) and add what you think you need until it happens again (just the html input and js/css includes) - if it doesn't happen, then continue to add what else is already in your application (other html, js/css and js/css includes) - one step at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Cross verify your code with below points. It may be due to below issues.

1. Input datepicker must be in type "text".
2. Make sure you are using only any one datepicker plugin css and js(bootstrap-datepicker/jquery-datepicker) files.
3. Also make sure the js file order is in correct order.

Comment: Yes, all the suggestions given have been checked. Still not working.

Comment: Then its due to jquery version mismatch with date picker version....Please try with any other datepicker lesser version or higher version. Then try again.

Comment: Checked all this still not working